# !git push:-- fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address||google colaboratory

Tags: github, push, google-colaboratory

I had cloned Github repo to google colab.
I want to push it to GitHub.
I get an error

how to configure GitHub to google colab such that I can push it to Github.

Answer (score 1):

this way works:

```
!git add .
!git commit -m "..."
!git remote set-url origin "https://<username>:<password>@github.com/<username>/<repo_name>"
!git push origin <branch_name>
```

according to [this document](https://medium.com/@navan0/how-to-push-files-into-github-from-google-colab-379fd0077aa8)